# deploying an asp.net application on multiple ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Suppose i have created an amazon load balancer with three ec2 instances :A,B,C.

Whenever  i deploy an asp.net app to the instance A ,Does Load  balancing deploy/updates it in the B,C instances?

If no,how one can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The ELB (load balancer) has nothing to do with the deployment, at least nothing useful. It's just there to split traffic to different instances for incoming (http) requests from clients.

**AWS Elastic Beanstalk (the easy way)**

Create an Elastic Beanstalk Application, where you deploy your asp.net application via the Amazon Visual Studio Toolkit. The process is very straightforward and it's not your part to do the deployment to all instances. After building and uploading the project to S3 beanstalk will distribute the new version to all instances within 20-60 seconds, depending on the size.

Advantage:

- very easy
- existing Tools
- it's Platform as a Service (PaaS), not Infrastructure as a Service (IaaS) which applies if you setup all AWS resources yourself.

Disadvantage:

- you can just deploy **ONE** "project" per Beanstalk App which means you are not able to deploy different "virtual directorie apps"
- maybe you need to build your own custom Beanstalk AMI, but usually you can use a AWS default image (beanstalk host manager needs to run on the instance, otherwise it will not work)
- you may lose a little bit of control, but imho that's not an issue

More Infos:

- https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/
- https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=86
- http://aws.amazon.com/visualstudio/

**The harder way**

If you have already setup a load balancer with 3 instances behind it's your task to deploy your code to all instances.

You could do that e.g. via Visual Studio and Web Deploy deploying to all 3 instances after another... you need to use the public dns name here of he instances itself, not the load balancer/app dns name.

You could use some kind of web server sync software for the app directories, e.g. MS web deploy, which should work, but the setup is not like fun imho and definitely more complex than Beanstalk.

More Infos:

- http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy